# "return" in foreach will only return one set of results, but echo returns all

Tags: loops, return

I have no idea why it will return all the values I'm looking for with echo, but only 1 set with "return".

I removed all the code within the first foreach statement to see if there was some conflict between the foreach statements, but it returns with the same result.

I've tried some of the suggestions on here that I thought might be relevant, but without any luck.

What could I possibly be doing wrong?

```
function getInvoiceTimeLog($project_unique_id, $user_id, $user_timezone, $time_format)
{

    global $db;

    $query = "SELECT t.task_id, t.unique_id, t.name, t.description, t.sub_total, p.project_id, p.user_id FROM task as t, task_project as tp, project as p WHERE t.task_id = tp.task_id AND tp.project_id = p.project_id AND p.unique_id = ".$db->prep($project_unique_id)." AND p.user_id = ".$db->prep($user_id)." ORDER BY t.name"; 
    $res = $db->query($query,'assoc');

    if($res != false) 
    {
        foreach($res as $row1): 

        $date = '';
        $prevDate = '';
        $return = '';

        $query = "SELECT a.track_id FROM task_track a INNER JOIN track_time b ON a.track_id = b.track_id WHERE a.task_id =".$db->prep($row1['task_id'])." ORDER BY FROM_UNIXTIME(b.time_start,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') DESC";
        $resT = $db->query($query,'assoc');

        $return .= '<div class="table" id="InvoicetimeLog"><div class="thead"><div class="th date">Date</div><div class="th start">Start</div><div class="th stop">Stop</div><div class="th hours">Hours</div></div><ul class="list">';

        $return .= '<li>'.$row1['description'].'</li>';

        if($resT != false)
        {
            foreach($resT as $row): 

                $track_id = $row['track_id'];   
                $query = "SELECT comment_id FROM track_comment WHERE track_id = ".$db->prep($track_id);
                $resComLink = $db->query($query,'assoc');
                if($resComLink != false)
                {
                    $query = "SELECT comment,time_left FROM comment WHERE comment_id = ".$db->prep($resComLink[0]['comment_id']);
                    $resComment = $db->query($query,'assoc');
                    $comment_class = 'comment_has';
                }
                else
                {
                    $comment = '';
                    $comment_class = 'comment';
                }

                $query = "SELECT time_start,time_end FROM track_time WHERE track_id = ".$db->prep($track_id);
                $resTime = $db->query($query,'assoc');
                $date = format_time($resTime[0]['time_start'],'m/d/y');

                if($date != $prevDate)
                {
                    $prevDate = format_time($resTime[0]['time_start'],'m/d/y');
                    $timeLog_ex = '<div class="date bold">'.$prevDate.'</div>';
                    $group = 'grp_shw';
                }
                else
                {
                    $timeLog_ex = '<div class="date bold"></div>';
                    $group = 'grp_no';
                }

                if($time_format == 'g')
                {
                    $the_time_format = 'g:i a';
                } 
                else 
                {               
                    $the_time_format = 'G:i';
                }       

                if(empty($resTime[0]['time_end']))
                {
                    $return .= '<li class="'.$group.'" id="rtrack_'.$track_id.'">'.$timeLog_ex.'<div class="start inlineEdit">'.date('m/d/y - '.$the_time_format,$resTime[0]['time_start']).'</div><div class="stop" title="The current time is at '.date($the_time_format,$db->nowUnix($user_timezone)).'">Current</div><div class="hours">'.getTimeDifference($resTime[0]['time_start'],$db->nowUnix($user_timezone)).'</div></li>';
                }
                else
                {
                    $return .= '<li class="'.$group.'" id="rtrack_'.$track_id.'">'.$timeLog_ex.'<div class="start inlineEdit">'.date('m/d/y - '.$the_time_format,$resTime[0]['time_start']).'</div><div class="stop">'.date('m/d/y - '.$the_time_format,$resTime[0]['time_end']).'</div><div class="hours">'.getTimeDifference($resTime[0]['time_start'],$resTime[0]['time_end']).'</div></li>';
                }
            endforeach;

            $return .= '<li class="grp_no"><div class="date bold">Total Time</div><div class="total">'.tot_time($unique_id,$user_id, $user_timezone).'</div></li>';
        }   

        $return .= '</ul></div>';

        endforeach;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: you should consider indenting the code inside blocks. It makes it much easier to read

Comment: How many rows are being returned? Can you add `var_dump($resT);` before `foreach($resT as $row)` line and see how many records you are getting? Perhaps there's just one record.

Comment: I get this: `array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["track_id"]=> string(2) "15" } [1]=> array(1) { ["track_id"]=> string(2) "14" } } array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { ["track_id"]=> string(2) "11" } [1]=> array(1) { ["track_id"]=> string(2) "12" } [2]=> array(1) { ["track_id"]=> string(2) "13" } }`

Comment: So it's returning track_id 5 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a dope I am.  It's simple....just move the variable declarations OUTSIDE of the foreach loop!

Move these guys to above the first foreach:

```
$date = '';
$prevDate = '';
$return = '';
```